# Can citrate in semen be utilized as a source of energy by the sperm?

Tags: human-biology, cell-biology, zoology, human-physiology, sexual-reproduction

Prostatic secretions of semen include citrate as one of the component.

The role of citrate in motility has been suggested by some researches.
(Kavanagh JP. Isocitric and citric acid in human prostatic and seminal fluid: Implications for prostatic metabolism and secretion. Prostate. 1994;24:139–42).

Is there a possibility, that it can be utilized as an energy source, and enter the citric acid cycle of mitochondria of spermatozoa?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Many microbes can use citrate as a carbon source for catabolism or anabolism. Citrate however is not a dominant (if at all) energy source for human cells  because transport of citrate across the cell membrane is not as efficient as those of monosaccharides such as glucose and fructose. Semen has high levels of fructose compared to other fluids in the body, and glucose and fructose are the primary sources of energy for sperm [1](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/15955884/). It is possible that citrate is important for sperm motility and viability through other mechanisms. If I can speculate, citrate could be a chelating agent in semen, but I do not have a source to back this up.